# MessageBox shows up at a specific time that the user inputs with an NumericUpDown

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void RemindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FinalMessage = "";

        //add text from the radio buttons 

        if (MathRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalMessage += MathRadioButton.Text;
        }

        if (HistoryRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalMessage += HistoryRadioButton.Text;
        }

        if (EnglishRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalMessage += EnglishRadioButton.Text;
        }

        if (ScienceRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalMessage += ScienceRadioButton.Text;
        }

        if (ElectiveRadioButton.Checked == true)
        {
            FinalMessage += ElectiveRadioButton.Text;
        }

        FinalMessage += " work from ";
        string Teacher_Name = TeacherNameTextBox.Text;
        FinalMessage += Teacher_Name + " is due on ";

        string Month = MonthNumericUpDown.Value.ToString();
        string Day = DayNumericUpDown.Value.ToString();
        string Str_Time = TimeNumericUpDown.Value.ToString();
       // int Int_Time = (int)TimeNumericUpDown.Value;

        FinalMessage += Month + "/" + Day + " at " + Str_Time;
        FinalMessage += " and is about " + DescriptionTextBox.Text;

        MessageBox.Show(FinalMessage);



}
```

So, I have this stored in by button, which simply concatenates all the users inputs. Still not sure how to have a message box show at a specific time that the user sets with a numericupdown and using DateTime.

Comment: A timer is the droid you are looking for. DateTime would only help you if you got some form of polling. Wich I strongly advise against. Note that there are 5+ Timers in .NET, wich one to use depends on your display technology. WPF/UWP, WindowsForms, ASP.Net, other? Please specify so we can help you.

Comment: Windows Form App

Comment: Oh wait, this is a Callendar/Reminder application. I did not even look at most of the code. Yeah, for that you will need a loop that does polling.

Answer (score 1):

Most simplistically we can have a timer that fires every minute and checks if the reminder date is in the past, and if it is, it shows the reminder text and then stops the timer. To schedule another reminder, pick a date in the future and start the timer again:

```
public class Reminder{

    private Timer _t = new Timer();

    private string _reminderText = "Remember remember!";
    private string _reminderDate = new DateTime(2019, 11, 16, 12, 34, 56); //12:34:56 on 16 nov 2019

    public Reminder(){ //constructor
        _t.Tick += TimerTick;
        _t.Interval = 60000;//60 seconds
    }

    private void TimerTick(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        if(DateTime.Now > _reminderDate)
        {
            _t.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show(_reminderText);

        }
    }

    private void RemindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        //add code in here to set the _reminderText, _reminderDate, and finally Start() the timer

    }
}
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to set the reminderText (you already have it as FinalMessage) and _reminderDate (some parsing of your inputs will be required, remember to make it a date in the future, as this is how our logic succeeds (if the time is in the past, the message will show immediately). After you set these things, start the timer

If you want a recurring reminder, instead of stopping the timer, rearrange the _reminderDate for another future date (tomorrow at the same time, for example)

Christopher comments that we could set the timer so it triggers on the reminder date - seems a reasonable alternative: Calculate the number of milliseconds between the reminder date and now, and set the Timer's interval to that..

If you have a timer that fires regularly, you could update the UI to provide a countdown in minutes until the next reminder - what you code very much depends on what you want to do

Comment: Calculate the number of milliseconds between the reminder date and now, and set the Timer's interval to that? Sure..

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` fires the Elapsed event on a different thread.  Be careful accessing GUI controls from there.

Comment: Thanks Lars, switched to windows forms Timer

Answer (score 1):

With asynchronous `Task.Delay()` you can do it in a simpler way without timer's boiler plate code.

Calculate delay time between now and provided time.
Use `DateTimePicker` to pick valid date and time instead of multiple number boxes.

Make event handler asynchronous by adding `async` keyword

```
private async void RemindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FinalMessage = "";

    //add text from the radio buttons 
    // ...

    FinalMessage += " work from ";
    string Teacher_Name = TeacherNameTextBox.Text;
    FinalMessage += Teacher_Name + " is due on ";

    DateTime reminderTime = DateTimePicker.Value;

    FinalMessage += {reminderTime:yyyy/MM/dd 'at' HH:mm}; // will print 2019/11/25 at 12:23
    FinalMessage += " and is about " + DescriptionTextBox.Text;

    // calculate delay from now
    var messageDelay = reminderTime - DateTime.Now;

    await Task.Delay(messageDelay);

    MessageBox.Show(FinalMessage);       
}
```

As @BenVoigt suggested
`Task.Delay` method has overload which accepts `CancellationToken`, with cancellation token you can cancel reminder later.
Below is simplified approach which handle only one reminder

```
// instance variable
private CancellationTokenSource _reminderTokenSource;

private async void CancelRimnderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _reminderTokenSource?.Cancel();
}
```

In reminder button create source and passs token to the `Task.Delay`

```
private async void RemindButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ... other code

    var messageDelay = reminderTime - DateTime.Now;
    _reminderTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    await Task.Delay(messageDelay, _reminderTokenSource.Token);

    MessageBox.Show(FinalMessage);  
}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that there's no way to interact with the delay after it is requested... you might want the overload that accepts both a timespan and a cancellation token.

Comment: @BenVoigt, true, but OP did not provide more information about how delay should be handled. Cancellation token source lifetime must exceed scope of event handler, so we need to save it to instance variable.  Does form/application handle only one reminder or multiple reminders? For multiple reminders we probably want save cancellation tokens into directory with some reminder identifier as a key. That mean we need provide some UI for displaying multiple reminders with button to cancel it. Too much questions to guess